# Resilience pattern for a long run task

Tags: java, distributed-computing

My application is hosted in a container, and in the real environment, there are 3 containers deployed.  Let me say, they are A, B and C.

The application needs to execute long run tasks.  So, this time, A starts a long run task.  And,  if A is down, I want either B or C to resume that task.  My current solution is, when A starts the task, A writes a timestamp, task status and an executing flag record to DB.  I have a timeout setting, for example, 2 hours.  B and C constantly query the database to find tasks whose statuses are not `finished` and `currentTime - the written timestamp` is more than 2 hours.  They then start to resume the tasks.

The solution has a problem.  For example, `task1` in DB meets the query status, and both B and C get to know `task1` needs to be resumed.  How should I only let either B or C to pick up the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution could be to implement a locking mechanism. E.g. an optimistic locking approach could look like this: B & C both try to pick up Task 1. They will have to write a lock to the database stating that they are the current owner. A was the previous owner. B writes a record with B as the current owner. C, by checking when writing whether the record still contains A as current owner can see that their request is outdated and C will give up.

Comment: Good idea.  Let me try and will get back to you.